# React Native : useMemo or useCallback to improve renderItem and FlatList performance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my react-native app I want to optimize a component that I use into my FlatList, I'd like for you to help me how I could improve the performace of the component.

I have read of useMemo and useCallback but I still don't know if they will help me to improve performance!

Things I already added (and improved performance already):

-use getItemLayout prop to pass item width, height
-remove inline render function adn instead do it like this:

```
const keyExtractor = (item) => item.id.toString();

const renderItem = ({item, index}) => <MatchItem2 key={item.id} match={item} index={index}></MatchItem2>;
```

This is my component

What the component does: it receives a match object, from that object I get the receiver user by comparing with logged user

```
export default MatchItem2 = observer((props) => 
{
    
    const [ user, setUser ] = useState(false);
    const root = useStore();
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const { match, index } = props;
    const { t } = useTranslation();


    useEffect(() => 
    {
        setUser(getMatch(match));
    }, []);


    const getMatch = (match) => {
        if(match.user_liked_id == root.userStore.user.id)
        {
            return match.matched;
        }
        else
        {
            return match.liked;
        }
    };


   



    return (
    
            
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1.0} style={{ width:115,alignItems:'flex-end' }}>
   { user && (
    <>
    <View style={{ width:100,alignItems:'center' }}>
   <View style={{width:100,height:100,borderRadius:100/2,borderWidth:4, ...index == 9 ? { borderColor:'#6E2579', } : { borderColor:user.moodColor },overflow:'hidden',position:'relative',alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
   <Text numberOfLines={1} style={{ fontSize:14, ...index == 9 ? { color:'red' } : { color:'black' }, fontFamily:'Lexend',marginVertical:5,fontWeight:'500' }}>{ index == 9 ? t('seeAll') : user.name }</Text>
   </View>
   </>
   )}
   </TouchableOpacity>
    );

});
```